# Combining multiple process substitution

Tags: bash, command-line, process-substitution

Suppose you tried something like this:

```
$ paste ../data/file-{A,B,C}.dat
```

and realize that you want to sort each file (numerically, let's suppose) before pasting. Then, using process substitution, you need to write something like this:

```
$ paste <(sort -n ../data/file-A.dat) \
        <(sort -n ../data/file-B.dat) \
        <(sort -n ../data/file-C.dat)
```

Here you see a lot of duplication, which is not a good thing. Because each process substitution is isolated from one another, you cannot use any brace expansion or pathname expansion (wildcards) that spans multiple process substitution.

Is there a tool that allows you to write this in a compact way (e.g. by giving `sort -n` and `../data/file-{A,B,C}.dat` separately) and composes the entire command line for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
eval paste '<(sort -n ../data/file-'{A,B,C}'.dat)'
```

Or to automate it as a function

```
sort_paste() {
  local n i cmd
  n=1 cmd=paste
  for i do
    cmd="$cmd <(sort -n -- \"\${$n}\")"
    n=$(($n + 1))
  done
  eval "$cmd"
}
sort_paste  ../data/file-{A,B,C}.dat
```

(in some `ksh` implementations, you need to replace `local` with `typeset`)

To adapt to any arbitrary command, (and to prove that `eval` can be safe when used properly), you could do:

```
xproc() {
  local n i cmd stage stage1 stage2 stage3
  cmd= xcmd= stage=1 n=1
  stage1='cmd="$cmd \"\${$n}\""'
  stage2='xcmd="$xcmd \"\${$n}\""'
  stage3='cmd="$cmd <($xcmd \"\${$n}\")"'
  for i do
    if [ -z "$i" ] && [ "$stage" -le 3 ]; then
      stage=$(($stage + 1))
    else
      eval 'eval "$stage'"$stage\""
    fi
    n=$(($n + 1))
  done
  eval "$cmd"
}

xproc paste '' sort -n -- '' ../data/file-{A,B,C}/dat
```

Comment: I don't like `eval`, but I see the arguments are securely handled above. The only concern I see is the handling of `$cmd`: it will go through the usual expansions. This is fine when `cmd` is fixed to `paste`, but it can be problematic when you want to generalize this and accept `cmd` from the command line, as in `local i n=1 cmd="$1"; shift; ...`.

Comment: +1 for proper eval. Your first version is completely fine (and the cleanest and most easy to maintain) since in this scenario you have full control over the string passed to eval.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), why `eval` can be dangerous to use. As you'll notice, it is a **very powerful tool**, but at the same time can **cause a lot of damage**.

The following script will do what you want - safely.

```
sort_ps () 
{ 
    local cmd="$1" p=()
    shift;
    for f in "$@"; do
        p+=(<(sort -n "$f"));
    done
    "$cmd" "${p[@]}"
}
```

EDIT: Mr. Chazelas is right. I fixed my solution, so you can now use `sort_ps paste file1.txt file2.txt file2.txt ... fileN.txt` instead. Thank you Stephane for reviewing my answer.

**Sample output:**

```
rany$ sort_ps sprunge foo1.txt foo.txt 
http://sprunge.us/EBZf?/dev/fd/62
http://sprunge.us/TQGC?/dev/fd/62
```

Comment: `eval` is dangerous when passed uncontrolled data which is not the case in the solution I gave. You forgot a "--" and a ";", you're not reporting errors of paste as the exit status. You're not accounting for a `$temp_dir` potentially present in the environment. It will fail if any argument contain slashes (as in the OP's question), you're not pasting in the order the files were given, you're not using process substitution as the OP requested: uses extra temp space, sorts run sequentially instead of concurrently, no cleanup upon SIGKILL.

Comment: I didn't expect the process substitutions to survive until the end where `"$cmd"` is actually executed, not right after each statement. When `sort_ps` is implemented as a shell function as above, `sort_ps echo ../data/file-{A,B,C}.dat` gives `/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 /dev/fd/61`, indicating they survive until the end indeed. However, when `sort_ps` is implemented as a shell script, it gives `/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/63`, which means each process substitution is terminated right after it is mentioned. How strange! I cannot find any official documentation about this.

Comment: Strange, but it seems to be [a feature](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n388) introduced in [bash-2.04](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/execute_cmd.c?id=bb70624e964126b7ac4ff085ba163a9c35ffa18f)

Comment: You're still missing a "--". Try running it on a file called passwd in a directory called "-o/etc"  for instance.

Comment: On bash-4.3.11(1)-release on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, even the shell function method gives `/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/63`, meaning that the process substitutions don't survive until the last command. So storing process substitutions in an array doesn't work.